# How to get input from dialog back into treeview pyqt5 python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a treeview and when a user clicks on the data type column there is a dialog that pops out

[image: Treeview]

Here is the dialog

[image]

I am wondering the best method to update my tree with a value from the dialog.

I have tried to remove and the setItem but the row I am getting from my index object is not always the row index if that row is a child and not a parent.

This code works and changes the value in the tree

```
datadialog = DataDialogNoParent()
datadialog.popDialogBox(index)
datadialog.exec_()
self.model.setItem(index.row(),index.column(),QStandardItem(datadialog.choice))
```

When I try and change these child elements I get strange results using the row and column from the QModelIndex object.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### tl;dr

Use `self.model.setData(index, datadialog.choice, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)`.

### Explanation

Let's see the arguments of `setItem()`:

> `QStandardItemModel.setItem(row, column, item)`

You can only give a row and a column. How should the model know if you want to set a *child* item? And child of what?

`setItem()` only works for two-dimensional data models (aka, tables), but you're using the model as a tree, which means that each index could have its own children indexes (each one having its row and column relative to its parent).
What you get from `index.row()` and `index.column()` is referred to the coordinates relative to the index [`parent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#parent).

In your case, the highlighted item is at row 1 and column 1, so using `setItem()` will result in setting the item at the second row and column of the model *root* (assuming that an item exists at those coordinates).

Using `setData` allows to set the data for a specific index, because it uses its three coordinates to do so: row, column and *parent*. Note that the `QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole` argument is required, because by default QStandardItemModel uses `EditRole`.

Comment: thank you this makes more sense than what I was trying. I will look at the setData method.